# Multi-thread WinForms app with 1Mbps VCP & MS Charts

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, charts

Could you please help by giving some ideas and hints how multi-thread WinForms application should be designed to achieve best performance?
At the moment I have single-thread apllication with many controls (buttons, labels, textboxes etc) and MS Chart with 4 Fastlines. Data is received from VirtualComPort this way:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        while (serialPort1.IsOpen && serialPort1.BytesToRead != 0)
        {
            int howManyBytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
            byte[] newData = new byte[howManyBytes];
            serialPort1.Read(newData, 0, howManyBytes);
            bufferString.AddRange(newData);
        }
    }
```

In timerX_Tick event with minimum interval *bufferString* is parsed as soon as it has enough data. Everything works fine when small amounts of data are processed like configuration frames, time sync etc. But my small app should act as simple oscilloscope - be triggered on rising or falling edge and draw input data on chart. When I start data transmission with 1Mbps baudrate GUI slowly begin to freeze (ie. update rate of label that displays number of received data points decreases) and finally it's not responding at all. And I haven't even activated portion of code responsible for adding points to chart :-/

So my question is how to separate threads to have responsive GUI and working data acquisition in background. Examples I have seen doesn't need to transport large amounts of data between threads. Here, I have to show received data points on chart so everything should be moved to GUI thread somehow.

I haven't used data binding till now. In previous app version points were added to series via chart1.Series[x].Points.AddXY(). Will be binding to external data table faster?

Comment: I would have suggested your UI has a preset update frequency, and that data read comes in on another thread, and updates a data set, that will be read by the update frequency, so that your UI maybe updating only every half second or even second. depending on the quantity of data, rather than external data table, it maybe an internal data source is faster, I would expect it to be.

Comment: You are right, batch data update should be faster than point-by-point, maybe with suspended layout etc. I will have to look at my parser if it could be optimized somehow. At the moment chart is disabled and it still looks like it's too slow. I'm not sure if simple splitting GUI and receive tasks will do the business. What more, I'm a little bit worried about MS Chart performance - even if I use Fastline style it tends to be slow when managing 4 plots of ie.100k points. I'm not sure if it uses any reduction of displayed points or tries to draw every point/line - I guess it's the second option.

Comment: If you have disabled chart and its still taking a long time, maybe its time for some serious performance interogation

Comment: Ok, I have found first performance problem. There is _bufferString.AddRange(newData);_ line in DataReceived event. bufferString is of type List<byte> and in parser I use bufferTail index to get element position in frame, ie. bufferString[bufferTail+i]. After frame parsing I should remove it from bufferString by bufferString.RemoveRange(0,bufferTail); bufferTail=0; but because of asynchronous data adding it causes problems and some bytes are periodically lost :-/ This is why I have added condition if(bufferString.Count==bufferTail) before that action. It's ok in short transmissions, not here..

Comment: Any idea how to remove parsed frames on the fly and not loosing any data? I was trying to add flag before clearing and while loop before _bufferString.AddRange(newData);_ that waits for false value of this flag but it doesn't work :-/

Comment: Maybe I should implement true circular buffer solution, with head and tail indexes etc. It won't need any data clearing because everthing is a matter of indexes managing...

Comment: Would a stack work better, you can just add to the bottom of the stack and take them off the top? A circular solution has benefits as it would effectively be a fixed size, but could you run into an issue where youre overwriting data not yet processed?

Comment: I think that List<byte> previously used as _bufferString_ was a stack-like solution but there is a problem with removing processed bytes. To avoid data overwriting circular buffer still has to be processed faster than adding of incoming data. When I limit frames per timerX_Tick UI is responsive but processing is too slow. With while loop limited only by _bufferString.Count>0_ condition UI freezes. It could also mean it's still too slow to exit tick event before new data arrives and needs processing...

Comment: Have you split the processing into a different thread? So its not the ui thread processing your data and handling the receive etc.

Comment: This is going to be my next step. But my problem is that parser which processes incoming frames is highly interconnected with controls on UI so I wonder how to change the code to avoid creating delegates for everything. Frame can contain datapoint but can also contain response for "read settings" button which should update several checkboxes, numericUpDowns etc. I have seen a solution with _InvokeEx_ but at the moment I have no idea how to use :)

Comment: This sounds like a great and fun project, and i guess really not a stack overflow thing but, in this day when threads are stupidly normal, it does seem odd that the ui thread needs you to write things to make it usable, why isnt it like that by default? Almost to the point why isnt your code by default in another thread... Anyway.. Detaching ui is a common need. Now, is the parser controlling the ui, or the ui controlling the parser? Ideally your parser shouldnt have any concept of a ui, the ui if necessary can maybe hook to events and properties of the parser, not the other way round

Comment: The main problem is that this WAS a small app for logging device service purposes, without any special needs or time constraints. Time was passing by and various things were added here and there but because everything was "offline" like downloading data from memory, config change etc, nobody cared if it was processed in 2s or 0.1s. Now we need an option of "online" data capturing and time becomes critical. I assume you mean that things should be reflected in local variables and UI should refer to them. At the moment control fields like _something_**.Value** are used directly in parser.

Comment: And why code is not in another thread? Hmm, probably because of limited access to UI controls. I have several buttons referring to controls values/selections, forming and sending frames via serialPort. On the second hand I have a device that answers to these frames and mentioned controls should be updated according to received data. It was an intuitive choice to put it into thread where these controls are accessible.